# Do we need to compile iOS App for both "armv7" and "arm64" if my deployment target is 8.0?

Tags: ios, cpu-architecture, armv7, arm64

My App supports from iOS8.0 and above. And I know that from iOS7 onwards its arm64 bit architecture. In that case do we need to compile the binary for both "armv7" and "arm64" slices?

If I compile for arm64 alone, I can reduce my App size. Is it a right way ?

Please help.

Answer (score 13):

[Here](https://docs.elementscompiler.com/Platforms/Cocoa/CpuArchitectures/) you can find very easy to understand explanation of all iPhone and also Mac CPU architectures.

It helped me a lot when I decided to remove armv7 architecture from my supported architectures:

> Choose carefully when excluding architectures. An application built with armv7 will run on all current iOS devices, even those that support newer architectures (it will run as 32-bit on iPhone 5S and later). But on the other hand, an app built without armv7 will not run on older devices such as the iPhone 4/4S or the original iPad mini.

Comment: Hi, do you finally remove armv7 support? Do you see any drawbacks in your app? Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding from Apple docs, The size of App will be reduce when you compile it for specific architecture and it's the correct way of doing it.

**Apple docs :**

> Target Fewer CPUs
>
> By default, Xcode projects are configured to generate optimized copies
>   of your app in CPU-specific "slices" of your executable. Different
>   hardware will run a different slice of the executable. This enables
>   powerful optimizations that are only possible on some devices.
>   However, this can substantially increase the size of your app's
>   executable.
>
> To target only specific CPUs, change the Architectures build setting
>   from Standard $(ARCHS_STANDARD) to a list of the names of specific
>   CPUs you want to support. Valid CPU names are listed in the Valid
>   Architectures (VALID_ARCHS) build setting. Do not change the Valid
>   Architectures setting. It is vestigial, and best managed by Xcode.

For more info refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1795/_index.html)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You need to build the app for both of these

Comment: This just shows that 64bit code is required.  It doesn't show that 32bit code is also required.

Comment: pls see the last line you have to build for both 32 and 64 bit

Comment: That just says it *recommends* using the "standard architecture" setting to ensure 64 bit support is provided.